# Mac OS X Tiger installation on VirtualBox freezes at verbose command line

Tags: install, virtualbox

I'm trying to install Mac OS X 10.4 on VirtualBox, but no matter how hard I try, it keeps freezing at the verbose mode command line after:

```
Got boot 
device = IOService:/AppleACPIPlatformExpert/PCIO@1e0000/AppleACPIPCI/pci8086,2829@1F,2/AppleAHCI.PRTO@0/IOACHIDevice@0/IOACHISerialATAPI/IOSCSIPeripheralDeviceNub/IOSCSIPeripheralDeviceType05/IODVDServices/IODVDBlockStorageDriver/VBOX
BSD root: disk 0s3, major 14, minor 2
```

The attached screenshot (below)[image: L]shows the problem. Does anyone know how to fix it?

P.S. the installation image is an x86 version of Tiger

Update 07/02/22: Today, I modified the VM settings and tried the installation again, but this time, instead of it freezing after the aforementioned code, I got a kernel panic at the command line, AND THEN it froze! This is really, REALLY bad!

Update 07/06/22: My dad gave me his iBook and PowerBook because he had no use of any of them anymore, so I decided to install Tiger on both of them and it worked perfectly (yay!). No need for a VM anymore!

Comment: Tiger isn't licensed for virtualisation [though I doubt anyone would really care these days] but precisely what version of 10.4? Before 10.4.4 there was no Intel Mac, so it's PPC only.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: These VMware instructions https://www.downtowndougbrown.com/2017/10/virtualizing-mac-os-x-10-4-with-vmware/ suggest you probably need a 10.4.10 DVD that came with a MacBookPro3,1. But maybe VirtualBox is more forgiving.

Comment: @Gilby Okay, so you suggested that I use a Mac OS X install DVD image that came with another Mac machine to install Tiger. What you're talking about is that you suggested that I would use a grey Mac OS X install disc that came with a MacBook Pro 3,1. Grey install discs that were bundled with other Mac machines fail to install when you try to use them on Mac machines other than the one they came with. A disk image of the retail Tiger install disc doesn't work on VirtualBox as it only works on PowerPC, so I found an x86 image of Tiger that supports VirtualBox and used it to install Tiger.

Comment: Edit: Here is the Archive.org link I used to get the x86 image of Tiger that supports VirtualBox: : https://archive.org/details/mac-os-x-10.4.8-ja-s-amd-intel-sse-2-sse-3-with-ppf-1-ppf-2